# how to configure edismax handler in sunspot?

Tags: sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

can any one explain how to start with using edismax request handler in sunspot?

I want to use wild card search in my application. currently dismax handler is there.i searched and found that edismax is only option for wild card search.****please give me some particular tutorial so that i can follow the same.****i searched in my application for edismax but not found any where.i checked in solrconfig.xml and schema.xml also.please tell me how to activate and deactivate request handler in sunspot. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following monkey patch to get the edismax request handler working with Sunspot.

https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/93

For development

Change gem file to use a pre-release of sunspot_solr (this uses Solr 3.x).

```
group :development do
  gem "sunspot_solr", "~> 2.0.0.pre.120925"
end
```

I then created an initializer with the patch described in the link above. There is no way to switch between the two request handlers with the given patch.

Answer (score 0):

`edismax` is the default parser as of sunspot_solr 2.2.0

References:

- https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/pull/487
- https://rubygems.org/gems/sunspot_solr